# Getting input of unlimited FAQs in Umbraco 5

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

My problem is that I want to get FAQs in my page from the Admin Panel, and the user can enter as much as he wants. We used to implement that in 4.7 with a usercontrol wrapper (populating the datatable from the Umbraco input XML to the datatable and then binding the datatable with the grid and vice versa).

How am I supposed to do it in Umbraco 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there is no way to do that for now, :(
but there is a way around, you can create subpages of the document with specific properties and load them in your cshtml i-e

FAQ

> FAQ1
>   FAQ2
>   FAQ3
>   FAQ4

with sub pages having two fields i-e Question and answer.
It is not optimum solutions but it is a work around and it will work in some cases.